# Ajustar imagen Bootstrap CSS

Tags: css, bootstrap

Estoy intentando hacer que un par de imágenes se ajusten al tamaño de la pantalla. Cuando es superior a `768` funciona sin problema y no quiero tocar esa medida, pero cuando reduzco a dispositivos pequeños la imagen no se ajusta.

Por más que consulto y pruebo no encuentro solución, si alguien pudiese orientarme con alguna página donde lo expliquen bien, porque no hago nada más que probar valores y yo creo que son varios los que tengo que cambiar, no uno solo.

Son tres fotos, una he conseguido que se vea bien tras poner un `background-size: contain;` pero las otras dos me dan el mismo error, pongo el código con el mismo estilo pero no sé si la solución será igual, espero que si.
Está hecho en `bootstrap 4.1.0`

Adjunto una imagen, en la otra otra imagen me pasa lo mismo.
Saludos a todos y gracias.

```
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-6">
      <h2>Nuestros Modelos</h2>
    </div>

  </div><!--Fin row-->

  <div class="row no-gutters modelo estandar align-items-end mt-4">

    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="contenido bg-light p-5 px-md-0">
        <h3>Estándar</h3>
        <p>Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Vestibulum pellentesque 
          vitae urna sit amet hendrerit.
        </p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-dark text-uppercase">Más información</a>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div><!--Fin row-->

  <div class="row no-gutters modelo premium justify-content-end mt-4">

    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="contenido bg-light p-5">
        <h3>Premium</h3>
        <p>Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Vestibulum pellentesque 
          vitae urna sit amet hendrerit.
        </p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-dark text-uppercase">Más información</a>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div><!--Fin row-->

  <div class="row no-gutters modelo gold mt-4">

    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="contenido bg-light p-5 px-md-0">
        <h3>Gold</h3>
        <p>Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Vestibulum pellentesque 
          vitae urna sit amet hendrerit.
        </p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-dark text-uppercase">Más información</a>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div><!--Fin row-->

</div><!--Fin container-->


   
.modelo {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    min-height: 40rem;
}
.estandar {
    background-image: url(../img/modelo_estandar_mini.jpg);
    background-size: contain;
}
.premium {
    background-image: url(../img/modelo_premium_mini.jpg);
    background-size: contain;
 }
.gold {
    background-image: url(../img/modelo_gold_mini.jpg);
    background-size: contain;
}
```

[image: problema imagen no responsive]

Comment: ¿podrías indicar una referencia de cómo quieres que quede? para entender bien la pregunta. Igualmente, ¿probaste el uso de las clases de dimensionado? `class='w-100'` por ejemplo.

Comment: Buenas, por favor recuerda que debes hacer un [mre]. El codigo otorgado no produce el mismo resultado que muestras en la imagen.

Answer (score 1):

Te dejo lo que hice, es probable que te sea de utilidad o al menos de referencia:

Este es el HTML prueba en un proyecto por separado

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Blocks</title>
    <!-- Do not change this file - add your CSS styling
         rules to the blocks.css file included below -->
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="blocks.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="one">
    Turns out you have a really fun time if you
    go to work every day and focus on being
    silly and funny and happy! - Hannah Murray
</div>
<div id="two">
    All you need in this life is ignorance and confidence,
    and then success is sure. - Mark Twain
</div>
<div id="three">
    Well, if crime fighters fight crime and fire fighters
    fight fire, what do freedom fighters fight? They never
    mention that part to us, do they? - George Carlin
</div>
<div id="four">
    Great minds discuss ideas; average minds discuss events;
    small minds discuss people. - Eleanor Roosevelt
</div>
<p id="link">
    <a href="https://www.brainyquote.com/" target="_blank">
        Brainy Quote
    </a>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

y este es el CCS

```css
body {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
/* Here is one of many  CSS rules you will need... */
div {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 5px;
}
#one {
    border-style: solid;
    width: 25%;
    border-color: chocolate;
    position: absolute; top: 10px; left: 25px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
#two {
    border-style: solid;
    width: 25%;
    border-color: red;
    position: absolute; top: 10px; left: 70%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
#three{
    border-style: solid;
    width: 25%;
    border-color: yellow;
    position: absolute; bottom: -10px;  left: 25px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
#four{
    border-style: solid;
    width: 25%;
    border-color: darkblue;
    position: absolute; bottom: -10px; left: 70%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
#link{
    width: 10%;
    position: absolute; top: 10px; left: 45%;
}
a{
    color: #fefefe;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #354eb1;
}
```

Los recuadros se ajustan al tamaño de la ventana, prueba el código y checa el CCS al menos si no soluciona tu problema , creo que te puede dar una idea.

Saludos

Comment: Para ese ejemplo si se ejecuta bien el width, yo lo he intentado en mi código con width y con max-width y no me muestra bien la imagen. 
Gracias compañero

Comment: el problema creo que tiene que ver con el background-size, porque cuando le pongo el cover me muestra el tamaño de la imagen completa, pero solo veo 1/4 de la imagen, esos conceptos no los tengo muy claros la verdad

Comment: Yo la verdad no uso mucho los CSS pero si me gusto este ejemplo, en algun momento me podria ser util, mira encontre alguna referencia sobre el uso del background-size, trae algunas explicacione, no sé si ya lo revisaste, pero te lo dejo algo de ha de servir:  https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/background-size

Comment: Gracias, lo estoy viendo y probando, no lo había visto y está bien explicado lo que no se es porqué no me funciona, me debería de funcionar el cover o el contain por lo que explica pero me hace dos cosas diferentes y ninguna correcta.
Gracias compañero

Answer (score 1):

Al final he dado con la respuesta, gracias Cesarin, un poco de lo que lo que leí en enlace y otro poco de algunos videos que vi he dado con la solución.
Algo más claro creo que me ha quedado pero tengo que practicarlo más, adjunto código para que veáis la solución:

```
.modelo {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
   min-height: 40rem;
}
.estandar {
    background-image: url(../img/modelo_estandar_mini.jpg);
    background-size: contain;
}
.premium {
    background-image: url(../img/modelo_premium_mini.jpg);
    background-size: contain;
    background-position: 100% 100%;
}
.gold {
    background-image: url(../img/modelo_gold_mini.jpg);
    background-size: contain;
    background-position: 100% 100%;
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Excelente que bueno que ya lograste dar con la solución